# Why do ships fall in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

I find it hard to believe that even though most, if not all, Star Wars ship battles take place out of the orbit of planets in space, why do capital ships fall if they take enough damage? In ROTJ, a courageous pilot flies his craft into the Imperial Super Star Destroyer and destroys the bridge but then it somehow falls into the Death Star. In Clone Wars, there are several instances of Venator Jedi Cruisers and Banking Clan Frigates "falling". Why do ships fall in space if there is no gravity?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before.

Comment: There's no gravity in space? Then why don't all the planets instantly fly apart?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - It has indeed.

Comment: "outer space" should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least the jnstance in ROTJ is easily explained: The Death Star is large enough (or rather has enough mass) to have its own gravity (albeit less than a planet), but stipl enough that a Super SSD like the Executor could "fall down" because of it.